# Creating "semi-regular" lists of dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, excel-auto-fill

Consider the Excel power user club of Wheatland, Wyoming. The club meets evey Thursday, plus every second Monday. So there are, alternating, weeks with two, and weeks with only one meeting. Let us call the Thursday-only weeks "A weeks", and the Thursday+Monday weeks "B weeks".

If the first meeting this year were next Thursday, a list of the upcoming dates would look like this:

- Thu 13 Aug 2020 (A week)
- Mon 17 Aug 2020 (B week)
- Thu 20 Aug 2020 (B week)
- Thu 27 Aug 2020 (A week)
- Mon 31 Aug 2020 (B week)

and so forth.

How can we have Excel automatically create a list of such a series of dates for a year or more?

My first intuitive attempt was to use the first date (say, in cell A1) as a starting point, and then set up the next few cells with these formulae:

```
=A$1+4 (Mon after the 1st Thu)
=A$1+7 (Thu after the 1st Thu)
=A$1+14 (2nd Thu after 1st Thu)
```

...and then hope for the auto fill feature to recognise the pattern. This didn't work, I ended up with identical copies of the sequence.

A second idea was to use the "series" feature based on these cells, with an increment of 14. But that feature seems to work only with a single cell as a starting point, it doesn't seem to be able of recognising patterns at all.

I can imagine there is a not-too complicated solution based on my first attempt -- but any other method is appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that:

- The first date is a Thursday
- The second date is the subsequent Monday

You have a sequence of three -- Thu - Mon - Thu which repeats.

You can generate that sequence in many ways. Here is one:

```
A1:  First Thursday
A2:  =IF(WEEKDAY(A1)=2,A1+3, IF(MOD(COUNT($A$1:A1),3)=1, A1+4,A1+7))
```

In other words:

- If the row above is a Monday, add 3 (to return Thursday)
- else decide whether to add 7 or 4 depending on how many dates have been entered to this point.

[image]

Comment: works perfectly, thanks very much! Using a MOD construction was the thing that I hadn't realised might be pretty useful.